# How to prevent server files from being viewable online?

Tags: apache, file, amazon-ec2

I have a website running on an Amazon EC2 Linux server, and everything works fine, but when I point the address bar to something like mydomain.com/css or mydomain.com/images, it prints out a list of all the files in that directory to the brower and they're all readable and viewable. I tried chmod'ing some of the folders to have fewer permissions, and that prevented viewing of these files, but it also made them not appear on the site at all. Is there a way that I can protect my documents and server files while also keeping full functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prevent the directory listing by disabling it in the Apache config. Just remove "Indexes" from whatever lines it appears on. For example, change from:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
```

To:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
```

Edit: Note, you can also add (or edit) the .htaccess in those directories, explicitly disabling indexing for that directory:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the nature of the web, these files are downloaded to the user's computer so the browser can display them. You cannot protect them from being called from your own site / URL but you can put rules into place that prevent "hotlinking," that is, it will prevent people from linking to the image in their website from your URL. But even then, they could download the file(s) then upload to their own space and carry on.

Sorry I don't have better news, hope this helps!

Comment: Oh ok. I guess I should've realized that. Thanks.

Comment: Well, if you look at Alex's answer I guess he read the question more carefully than I did - if its JUST the directory listing you want to prevent, then follow his steps below.